# Querying graphiql leads Apollo error forward is not a function

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphiql

I have an express back-end with GraphQL that works when I go to `/graphiql`and manually perform some searches. My React front-end is trying to perform a search on the back-end. The following code should perform the query asynchronously:

```
const data = await this.props.client.query({
    query: MY_QUERY,
    variables: { initials: e.target.value }
});
console.log(data);
```

Where `MY_QUERY` is defined before and represents a query that I know works and has been tested on `/graphiql`. To do this in my React component I export it as `export default withApollo(MyComponent)` so that it has the `client` variable in the `props`.

In the `index.js` file I defined through Apollo the connection to `/graphiql` in order to perform the queries:

```
//link defined to deal with errors, this was found online
const link = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors)
        graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
        console.log(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
        ),
        );

    if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});

//the httpLink to my GraphQL instance, BASE_URL is defined elsewhere
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: BASE_URL,
    headers: {
    },
});

//here I define the client linking the GraphQL instance, the cache, and error handling
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache,
    link
});
```

When executing the above mentioned query without the `link`variable that handles the error, I receive a `400 Bad Request` from the server (`ApolloError.js:37 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400`). Since this doesn't tell me more, here on StackOverflow and on the Apollo Web page I've found the above error declaration that outputs `[Network error]: TypeError: forward is not a function`. What does this error mean and how do I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your client configuration has a duplicate property -- you first set the `link` property to your `HttpLink` and then set it again to your `ErrorLink`. This means the `HttpLink` is ignored completely, and you're only passing in the `ErrorLink` to the configuration. You're seeing that error because the `ErrorLink` created by `onError` is not meant to be used by itself. Instead, it should be chained with the `HttpLink` and that's what you should assign to the `link` property.

[This page](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/composition.html) in the docs details how to correctly compose links. You can use `concat` but I prefer `ApolloLink.from` since it allows you to clearly show the order of your links:

```
const errorLink = onError(...)
const httpLink = new HttpLink(...)
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  errorLink,
  httpLink,
])
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
})
```